# How to Wrap Text in HTML Option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to put a dropdown list on my page, As one option is too long, when I click the select menu, it will expand and cover the other part of the page.

```
<select id="selectlist" name="SelectProgram">

    <option value="LIR" >LIR</option>
        <option value="How to word wrap text in HTML?">How to word wrap text in HTML? CSS / HTML text wrap for webkit</option>
```

The second option is too long and will expand. Is there any way I could wrap such a long text into 2 lines?
Thank you!

Comment: No, you can't wrap the text in a native select. I suggest setting the width of the select to a fixed width.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seeing as the value and text of a Select can be very different. I would say if in the event a string thats in your select for the text is longer than X truncate it.

Example with jquery

```
$('#myselect option').each(function()
{
    var myStr = $(this).text();
    if(myStr.length > 15){$(this).text(myStr.substring(15));}
});
```

put that in your document ready, and it will trim your text down to a better size, wrapping your elements in a div that will hide the overflow is going to make something of a mess later, and you will be back here trying to solve a similar issue caused by that for strings that are smaller.

Comment: +1, I wouldn't have thought of this

Comment: Two things to improve this code: use `substring(0,15)` or else the FINAL 15 characters will be grabbed.  In addition, I like to add ellipses whenever option text is truncated, so the user knows it has been, such as: `text(myStr.substring(0,15) + '...')`.  Answer edited to include these...

Comment: Another quick comment: be careful about extra whitespace in your HTML between option texts when using this Javascript.  Your browser might have scrubbed it out, but the JS `length` method will not.

Comment: This chopped off the first few strings. My users won't know what they are selecting. I'd prefer a text wrap not a text chop off.

Answer (score 5):

Setting a fixed width can be done without the wrapping `div` by simply using

```
<select id="selectlist" name="SelectProgram" style="width: 500px">
   <option value="LIR" >LIR</option>
   <option value="How to word wrap text in HTML?">How to word wrap text in HTML? CSS / HTML text wrap for webkit</option>
</select>
```

In practice, you should put `width: 500px` in a matching rule in your CSS file.

Comment: great - this worked great for me

Comment: user can't see the rest of the text to the right... users don't know exactly/fully what they are selecting.

Answer (score 0):

wrap that input in a div, put some width for div, so that line will not go outside the div, lik below :

```
<div id="something" style="width:500px">
  <select id="selectlist" name="SelectProgram">
     <option value="LIR" >LIR</option>
     <option value="How to word wrap text in HTML?">How to word wrap text in HTML? CSS / HTML text wrap for webkit</option>
  </select>
</div>
```